# Why to shift bits "$? >> 8" when using Perl system function to execute command

Tags: perl, shell

I have seen this in many places in Perl scripts:

```
system("binary");
$exit_code = ($? >> 8)
exit($exit_code)
```

1. Why should I use this?  Is there an alternative way?
2. I am calling some binary in `system(binary)` which I created in C++, which does some stuff and if it fails it gives `assert`. When I reboot a Linux machine, the stuff which is going fails, and my binary generates `assert` as expected.  But on the Perl side where I called it, it throws a `134` error code, which after `134 >> 8`, becomes `0`. Ultimately it is making my failure operation a *success* (which I don't want).

Comment: Why did you start using the bit shift? Was it already there? Did you take it from somewhere?

Comment: You actually observed a value of 134? The answer below suggests that shouldn't happen.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder looks like `$status` isn't being set...

Comment: @TomFenech: I was wondering about the `$?` (in the title) vs. `$status` (in the code) thing, but I don't know enough (read: basically anything) about Perl...

Comment: Sry actually its $? not $status @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The program executed under `system` may return a specific code when it exits. That is packaged into high bits of a number (*exit status*) which Perl gets and which is available in `$?`. This is why you want to test that number, for example (but see below)

```
system($cmd) == 0  or die "Error: $?";
```

Or, you can separately check [$?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables) after the call. If true (non-zero), that only means that there was something other than a clean exit by the application, or a problem with `system` itself.  When you unpack that you are looking for what the application communicated on its exit. In order to merely see whether there was an error you only look at `$?`, and you *are* getting a value.  So there is no conflict.

What code that program returned is its business (design decision). Programs ideally exit with codes when they fail (if they can detect and handle the problem), and have documentation explaining what code means what. For an example see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35593723/unable-to-capture-stderr-while-performing-openssh-to-a-variable-perl/35594073#35594073), and for another comment [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22762710/perl-after-a-successful-system-call-or-die-command-still-ends-script/35543666#35543666).

As seen in [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html), you readily get: exit code `$? >> 8`, signal number `$? & 127`, and whether core was dumped `$? & 128`. With your exit status of `134` the signal number is `6`, which `man 7 signal` lists as `SIGABRT`. The core should be there as well. So that is what you got from your program, and no explicit exit code. Apparently, the program caused abort and dumped core.

In your case, you know where all this comes from -- `assert` is a macro which calls `abort`, whereby `SIGABRT` is raised (`man 3 assert abort`). Perl gets back that `6` packaged into `134`.

---

Note that `assert` prints a message to `STDERR`, so you may want to run the program via `qx` (backticks), in which case you can capture that error. See the first link above, or search on SO.

Comment: Yes, I know the solution for fix, i will just remove shifting to solve it, But i need a valid reason when to use shifting with system() and when not to use?

Comment: What you said it does really makes sense i found something, The system() function returns two numeric values folded into one. The first is the Unix signal (e.g INT=2, QUIT=3, KILL=9), if any, that terminated the command. This is stored in the lower eight bits returned. The next higher eight bits contain the exit code for the command you executed.

Comment: @Dipal  Yes! That's the point.  Even as the program just sent back a zero the OS knew that something was wrong (signal) and returned to Perl a non-zero.

Comment: Yes assert is an termination condition so it came in lower 8 bit and there was no error code so higher 8 bits are 0. Am i right now?

Comment: I found it it was core dump that's why 128 bit was set from lower 8 bit and plus 6 for assert so finally it was 128|6 = 134

Comment: @Dipak  Nice.  Now, there are other tools in Perl for this.  If nothing else, modules that make it easier and cleaner.  I haven't used them enough to recommend, but there is a lot of good advice on SO.

Answer (score 8):

`perldoc -f system` snippet:

> The return value is the exit status of the program
>                  as returned by the `wait` call.  To get the actual
>                  exit value divide by 256.
>
> You can check all the failure possibilities by
>                  inspecting `$?` like this:
>
> ```
> $exit_value  = $? >> 8;
> $signal_num  = $? & 127;
> $dumped_core = $? & 128;
> ```

Comment: So my assert (134) is also one of failure so why it is making it 0 by doing >>8 ?

Comment: And can you please describe about wait call? what is it?

Comment: wait, waitpid, waitid - wait for process to change state. more details you can obtain using man 2 wait.